# How to retrieve a list of all Meta keys and values for a particular component in SDL Web 8

Tags: brokerquery

I want to retrieve all Meta keys and value for a particular component , I am using web forms and I have duplicate Meta key's in my Custom_meta table. I want to read them on content delivery side.
[image]

The code I have tried

```
string templateUri = "tcm:3-4-32";
ComponentPresentationFactory cpf = new ComponentPresentationFactory(3);
ComponentMetaFactory cmf = new ComponentMetaFactory(3);
Criteria criteria = new ItemTypeCriteria(16);
Query query = new Query(criteria);
foreach (string uri in query.ExecuteQuery())
{
    ComponentPresentation cp = cpf.GetComponentPresentation(uri, templateUri);
    // check if component presentation is published to the broker
    if (cp != null)
    {
        IComponentMeta meta = cmf.GetMeta(uri);
        CustomMeta customMeta = meta.CustomMeta;
        foreach (DictionaryEntry de in customMeta.NameValues)
        {
            Response.Write(string.Format("{0}: {1} ({2})<br/>", 
                           de.Key, 
                           ((NameValuePair) de.Value).Value, 
                           ((NameValuePair) de.Value).Name));
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't give me the value for both the articles , I get only 4 entries in my log, so only one article value.(may be because of key is duplicate) , is there any way to read Duplicate Keys from Custom Meta?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    string templateUri = "tcm:3-4-32";
    ComponentPresentationFactory cpf = new ComponentPresentationFactory(3);
    ComponentMetaFactory cmf = new ComponentMetaFactory(3);
    Criteria criteria = new ItemTypeCriteria(16);
    Query query = new Query(criteria);
    foreach (string uri in query.ExecuteQuery())
    {
        ComponentPresentation cp = cpf.GetComponentPresentation(uri, templateUri);
        // check if component presentation is published to the broker
        if (cp != null)
        {
            IComponentMeta meta = cmf.GetMeta(uri);
            CustomMeta customMeta = meta.CustomMeta;
             NameValuePair nvp = (NameValuePair)customMeta.NameValues["Articles"];

             int i = 0;
            foreach (var s in nvp.MultipleValues)
            {
                allComponentUris[i] = Convert.ToString(s);
                i++;
            }
        }

    }
```